# Do Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange have the same questions?

Tags: support

I'm asking this question to know if Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange are related or not. **When I ask a question on Stack Overflow does it show in Stack Exchange?**

Comment: short answer is No - long answer is, check it yourself... look at meta and do a search for a question you see here in SO - you will not find it there.

Comment: i do it when i'm asking this question hhh

Comment: Please see [What is "Meta"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 7):

No, Meta Stack Overflow is not the same as Meta Stack Exchange.  They are separate sites with separate (yet highly overlapping) communities.

Each network site has what is known as a "per-site Meta".  Mathematics, Tex and Unix and Linux each have their own Meta site.  Stack Overflow has its own meta site analogous to these as well, where members of Stack Overflow can discuss topics that are specific to Stack Overflow.

Meta Stack Exchange is a bit special in that it serves as the central hub for all *general* meta discussions, for things that can equally apply to each site in the network, or for company-wide announcement-style posts.